# Finite 2 player game with infinitely many Nash Equilibria but none is Pareto optimal

Tags: game-theory, algorithmic-game-theory

I am looking for an example of a finite 2 player game that has infinitely many Nash equilibria of which none are Pareto optimal.

I have found a few cases of infinitely many Nash equilibria, but I am struggling to find one which is non-Pareto optimal.

I'm wondering about the special case of all zeros in the bimatrix - would this be "non Pareto-optimal"?

Any help is appreciated! Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: AFAIK, the usual definition of Pareto optimal says it is impossible to improve the payoff of one player without decreasing the payoff of some other player.  If the bimatrix is all zeros, it is always impossible to improve a payoff, so every pair of strategies is Pareto optimal.

Comment: Thank you for commenting! I wondered if that was the case but I wasn't exactly sure in that situation. This still doesn't bring me much closer to finding an example to the question that is non-pareto optimal though! Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the following $3 \times 3$ game
$$\begin{array}{c|ccc}
& L & C & R \\ \hline
T & 0,0 & 0,0 & 3,-1 \\
M & 0,0 & 0,0 & 2,-1 \\
B & -1,3 & -1,2 & 1,1\\
\end{array}$$
A strategy profile is a Nash equilibrium if and only if it puts positive probability only on $\{L,C\} \times \{T,M\}$; so there are infinitely many Nash equilibria, all with (expected) payoffs $(0,0)$.

However, the payoff $(0,0)$ is pareto-dominated by the payoff $(1,1)$ corresponding to the (non-equilibrium) strategy profile $(B,R)$.

Comment: Thank you so much for posting an example! That's great (I've constructed a lot of other "special cases", but I couldn't get my head around how such a game would look). Your answer is much appreciated!